# Ubuntu 12.04 graphics crashing when GVIM opens TEX files

Tags: unity, gnome, latex, gvim

I am having a little problem everytime when I open GVIM to edit `*.tex` files. The Menus *die*, Windows *jiggle (maximize and minimize quickly)* and I get a `internal error`  crash report from ubuntu (12.04).

It says the problem is at `/usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service`.

Package: unity-services 5.20.0-0ubuntu2
Problem: Crash
Title:   Unity-panel-service crashed with SIGSEGV in g_main_context_dispatch()

Any tips on how to solve this?

It might be related to the Latex package of vim.

Also I get this message when I open gvim (with or without TEX files) on terminal:

```
(gvim:5915): Gnome-WARNING **: Accessibility: failed to find module 'libgail-gnome' which is needed to make this application accessible

(gvim:5915): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot retrieve class for invalid (unclassed) type `<invalid>'
```

I just checked it, that the Issue is independant of theme.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

A quick search shows me that such module is in the repositories, you could try installing it and see if it makes the difference:

```
sudo apt-get install libgail-3-0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I already had that module installed.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround from [launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+question/202619):

```
apt-cache policy
apt-cache policy libgail-3-0 libgail18 libgail-common
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```